# algebraic sum of a graph of continuous function and itself Borel or measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $f\colon[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function.

Let $G\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ be a graph of $f$.

Does $G+G$ have to be:

a Borel set?

Lebesgue measurable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $t\mapsto(t,f(t))$ is continuous, $G$ is compact. So $G\times G$ is compact. Since $+:\Bbb R^2\times\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$ is continuous, $G+G$ is compact.