# algebraic sum of a graph of continuous function and itself - measure > 0 imply nonempty interior?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $f\colon[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function.

Let $G\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ be a graph of $f$.

Then $G+G$ is compact:
[algebraic sum of a graph of continuous function and itself Borel or measurable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1790903/algebraic-sum-of-a-graph-of-continuous-function-and-itself-borel-or-measurable)

so it is measurable.

Assume $G+G$ has positive measure.

Does it imply that $G+G$ has nonempty interior?

Comment: it seems to me that $G+G$ has almost never empty interior. It's the case when $f$ is afine but i don't find any other example. Do you have one ?

Answer (score 4):

As Renart suggested, if $f$ is not affine then $G+G$ has non-emmpty interior, while if $f$ is affine then $G+G$ lies in an affine subspace of $\Bbb R^2$ and hence has zero measure.

For $x\in[0,2]$ let $$I_x=\{y:(x,y)\in G+G\}.$$ If $x=a+b$ with $a,b\in[0,1]$ then $$I_x=\{f(a+t)+f(b-t):a+t,b-t\in[0,1]\}.$$The set of all $t$ with $a+t,b-t\in[0,1]$ is a closed interval, and $I_x$ is a continuous image of this interval. 
So each $I_x$ is a (possibly degenerate) closed interval.

If  $I_x$ consists of a single point for every $x\in(0,2)$ it follows that $$f(a+t)+f(b-t)=f(a)+f(b)$$whenever $a+t,b-t\in(0,1)$, and this shows that $f$ is affine. (Hint: Show that $f((s+t)/2)=(f(s)+f(t))/2$...)

Suppose on the other hand that $x\in(0,2)$ and $I_x=[\alpha,\beta]$ with $\alpha<\beta$. Choose $\epsilon\in(0,(\beta-\alpha)/2)$. Since $f$ is continuous it follows that $$[\alpha+\epsilon,\beta-\epsilon]\subset I_{x'}$$for all $x'$ in some neighborhood of $x$; hence $G+G$ has nonempty interior.

Comment: Nice proof, i had an easy one for $C^1$ functions but this is obviously better !